# Bar colors in ggplot2 geom_bar not applied correctly (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2

The bar fill colors are not applied correctly in the following plot. The fill colors of the groups of bars should be:

```
 [1] "gold3"         "darkgreen"     "darkgrey"      "white"        
 [5] "forestgreen"   "darksalmon"    "darkseagreen1" "deeppink"     
 [9] "mediumblue"    "darkmagenta"
```

But they are instead:

```
 [1] "deeppink"        "gold3"    "dark green"      "dark magenta"        
 [5] "darkseagreen1"   "white"    "forestgreen"     "darksalmon"     
 [9] "mediumblue"      "darkgrey"
```

**Why are the bar fill colors not applied correctly in the plot?**

Here are some of the data:

```
target_data=structure(list(UnitCode = c("DE-001-A", "DE-001-A", "DE-001-A", 
"DE-001-A", "DE-001-B", "DE-001-B", "DE-001-B", "DE-001-B", "DE-001-C", 
"DE-001-C", "DE-001-C", "DE-001-C", "DE-002-A", "DE-002-A", "DE-002-A", 
"DE-002-A", "DE-002-A", "DE-002-A", "DE-002-A", "DE-002-A", "DE-002-A", 
"DE-002-A", "DE-002-A", "DE-002-A", "DE-002-A", "DE-002-A", "DE-002-A", 
"DE-002-A", "DE-002-A", "DE-002-A", "DE-002-A", "DE-002-A", "DE-002-B", 
"DE-002-B", "DE-002-B", "DE-002-B", "DE-002-B", "DE-002-B", "DE-002-B", 
"DE-002-B", "DE-002-B", "DE-002-B", "DE-002-B", "DE-002-B", "DE-002-B", 
"DE-002-B", "DE-002-B", "DE-002-B", "DE-002-B", "DE-002-B", "DE-002-B", 
"DE-002-B", "DE-002-C", "DE-002-C", "DE-002-C", "DE-002-C", "DE-002-C", 
"DE-002-C", "DE-002-C", "DE-002-C", "DE-002-C", "DE-002-C", "DE-002-C", 
"DE-002-C", "DE-002-C", "DE-002-C", "DE-002-C", "DE-002-C", "DE-002-C", 
"DE-002-C", "DE-002-C", "DE-002-C", "DE-002-D", "DE-002-D", "DE-002-D", 
"DE-002-D", "DE-002-D", "DE-002-D", "DE-002-D", "DE-002-D", "DE-002-D", 
"DE-002-D", "DE-002-D", "DE-002-D", "DE-002-D", "DE-002-D", "DE-002-D", 
"DE-002-D", "DE-002-D", "DE-002-D", "DE-002-D", "DE-002-D", "DE-002-E", 
"DE-002-E", "DE-002-E", "DE-002-E", "DE-002-E", "DE-002-E", "DE-002-E", 
"DE-002-E", "DE-002-E", "DE-002-E", "DE-002-E", "DE-002-E", "DE-002-E", 
"DE-002-E", "DE-002-E", "DE-002-E", "DE-002-E", "DE-002-E", "DE-002-E", 
"DE-002-E", "DE-002-F", "DE-002-F", "DE-002-F", "DE-002-F", "DE-002-F", 
"DE-002-F", "DE-002-F", "DE-002-F", "DE-002-F", "DE-002-F", "DE-002-F", 
"DE-002-F", "DE-002-F", "DE-002-F", "DE-002-F", "DE-002-F", "DE-002-F", 
"DE-002-F", "DE-002-F", "DE-002-F", "DE-003-A", "DE-003-A", "DE-003-A", 
"DE-003-A", "DE-004-A", "DE-004-A", "DE-004-A", "DE-004-B", "DE-004-B", 
"DE-004-B", "DE-004-B", "DE-004-C", "DE-004-C", "DE-004-C", "DE-005-A", 
"DE-005-A", "DE-005-A", "DE-005-A", "DE-005-B", "DE-005-B", "DE-005-B", 
"DE-005-B", "IL-001-G", "IL-001-G", "IL-001-G", "IL-001-G", "IL-001-G", 
"IL-001-G", "IL-001-G", "IL-001-G", "IL-001-G", "IL-001-G", "IL-001-G", 
"IL-001-J", "IL-001-J", "IL-001-J", "IL-001-J", "IL-001-J", "IL-001-J", 
"IL-001-J", "IL-001-J", "IL-001-K", "IL-001-K", "IL-001-K", "IL-001-K", 
"IL-001-K", "IL-001-K", "IL-001-K", "IL-001-K", "IL-001-L", "IL-001-L", 
"IL-001-L", "IL-001-L", "IL-001-L", "IL-001-L", "IL-001-L", "IL-001-L", 
"IL-001-L", "IL-001-M", "IL-001-M", "IL-001-M", "IL-001-M", "IL-001-M", 
"IL-001-M", "IL-001-M", "IL-001-M", "IL-001-M", "IL-001-M", "IL-001-M", 
"IL-001-N", "IL-001-O", "IL-001-P", "IL-001-P", "IL-001-P", "IL-001-P", 
"IL-001-P", "IL-001-P", "IL-001-P", "IL-001-P", "IL-001-P", "IL-001-P", 
"IL-001-P", "IL-004-A", "IL-004-A", "IL-004-A", "IL-004-A", "IL-004-B", 
"IL-004-B", "IL-004-B", "IL-004-B", "IL-004-B", "IL-004-B", "IL-004-C", 
"IL-004-D", "IL-004-D", "IL-004-E", "IL-004-E", "IL-004-E", "IL-004-E", 
"IL-004-E", "IL-004-E", "IL-004-E", "IL-004-E", "IL-004-F", "IL-004-F", 
"IL-004-F", "IL-004-F", "IL-004-F", "IL-004-F", "IL-004-I", "IL-004-I", 
"IL-004-I", "IL-004-I", "IL-004-I", "IL-004-J", "IL-004-J", "IL-004-J", 
"IL-004-J", "IL-004-J", "IL-004-J", "MA-001-LP", "MA-001-LP", 
"MA-001-LP", "MA-001-LP", "MA-001-LP", "MA-001-LP", "MA-001-LP", 
"MA-001-LP", "MA-001-LP", "MA-001-LP", "MA-001-LP", "MA-001-LP", 
"MA-001-LP", "MA-001-UP", "MA-001-UP", "MA-001-UP", "MA-001-UP", 
"MA-001-UP", "MA-001-UP", "MA-001-UP", "MA-001-UP", "MA-001-UP", 
"MA-001-UP", "MA-001-UP", "MA-001-UP", "MA-001-UP", "MO-002-A", 
"MO-002-A", "MO-002-A", "MO-002-A", "MO-002-A", "MO-002-A", "MO-002-A", 
"MO-002-A", "MO-002-A", "MO-002-A", "MO-002-A", "MO-002-D", "MO-002-D", 
"MO-002-D", "MO-002-D", "MO-002-D", "MO-002-D", "MO-002-D", "MO-002-D", 
"MO-002-E", "MO-002-E", "MO-002-E", "MO-002-E", "MO-002-E", "MO-002-E", 
"MO-002-F", "MO-002-F", "MO-002-F", "MO-002-F", "MO-002-F", "MO-002-F", 
"MO-002-F", "MO-002-F", "MO-002-F", "MO-002-G", "MO-002-G", "MO-002-G", 
"MO-002-G", "MO-002-G", "MO-002-G", "MO-002-G", "MO-002-H", "MO-002-H", 
"MO-002-H", "MO-002-H", "MO-002-H", "MO-002-JJ", "MO-002-JJ", 
"MO-002-JJ", "MO-002-JJ", "MO-002-JJ", "MO-002-JJ", "MO-002-JJ", 
"MO-002-JJ", "MO-002-JK", "MO-002-JK", "MO-002-JK", "MO-002-JK", 
"MO-002-JK", "MO-002-K", "MO-002-K", "MO-002-K", "MO-002-K", 
"MO-002-K", "MO-002-K", "MO-002-K", "MO-002-K", "MO-002-L", "MO-002-L", 
"MO-002-L", "MO-002-L", "MO-002-L", "MO-002-L", "MO-002-L", "MO-002-L", 
"MO-002-L", "MO-002-L", "MO-002-L", "MO-002-M", "MO-002-M", "MO-002-M", 
"MO-002-M", "MO-002-M", "MO-002-M", "MO-002-M", "MO-002-M", "MO-002-M", 
"MO-002-M", "MO-002-N", "MO-002-N", "MO-002-N", "MO-002-N", "MO-002-N", 
"MO-002-N", "MO-002-N", "MO-002-N", "MO-002-N", "MO-002-O", "MO-002-O", 
"MO-002-O", "MO-002-O", "MO-002-O", "MO-002-O", "MO-002-O", "MO-002-O", 
"MO-002-O", "MO-002-O", "MO-002-P", "MO-002-P", "MO-002-P", "MO-002-P", 
"MO-002-P", "MO-002-P", "MO-002-P", "MO-002-P", "MO-002-P", "MO-002-P", 
"MO-002-Q", "MO-002-Q", "MO-002-Q", "MO-002-Q", "MO-002-Q", "MO-002-Q", 
"MO-002-Q", "MO-002-Q", "MO-002-Q", "MO-002-Q", "MO-002-Q", "MO-002-R", 
"MO-002-R", "MO-002-R", "MO-002-R", "MO-002-R", "MO-002-R", "MO-002-R", 
"MO-002-R", "MO-002-R", "MO-002-S", "MO-002-S", "MO-002-S", "MO-002-S", 
"MO-002-S", "MO-002-S", "MO-002-S", "MO-002-S", "MO-002-S", "MO-002-T", 
"MO-002-T", "MO-002-T", "MO-002-T", "MO-002-T", "MO-002-T", "MO-002-T", 
"MO-002-T", "MO-002-T", "MO-002-T", "MO-002-V", "MO-002-V", "MO-002-V", 
"MO-002-V", "MO-002-V", "MO-002-V", "MO-002-V", "MO-002-V", "MO-002-V", 
"MO-002-V", "MO-002-V", "MO-002-W", "MO-002-W", "MO-002-W", "MO-002-W", 
"MO-002-W", "MO-002-W", "MO-002-W", "MO-002-W", "MO-002-W", "MO-002-X", 
"MO-002-X", "MO-002-X", "MO-002-X", "MO-002-X", "MO-002-X", "MO-002-X", 
"MO-002-X", "MO-002-X", "MO-002-X", "MO-002-X", "MO-004-A", "MO-004-A", 
"MO-004-A", "MO-004-A", "MO-004-A", "MO-004-A", "MO-004-A", "MO-004-A", 
"MO-004-A", "MO-004-A", "MO-005-A", "MO-005-A", "MO-005-A", "MO-005-A", 
"MO-005-B", "MO-005-B", "MO-005-B", "MO-005-B", "MO-005-B", "MO-006-A", 
"MO-007-A", "MO-007-A", "MO-007-A", "MO-007-A", "MO-007-A", "MO-007-A", 
"MO-007-A", "MO-007-A", "MO-007-A", "MO-007-B", "MO-007-B", "MO-007-B", 
"MO-007-B", "MO-007-B", "MO-007-B"), Minutes = c(84, 280, 264, 
552, 14, 270, 176, 88, 42, 360, 160, 186, 550, 456, 276, 363, 
825, 836, 567, 870, 752, 1378, 1170, 1625, 760, 400, 940, 1134, 
1092, 1140, 1564, 742, 450, 440, 440, 288, 672, 510, 315, 675, 
470, 1075, 840, 912, 688, 448, 936, 756, 1386, 594, 1320, 372, 
390, 324, 180, 210, 385, 481, 245, 224, 456, 1000, 738, 946, 
720, 364, 325, 688, 760, 490, 570, 405, 280, 228, 235, 360, 48, 
644, 92, 180, 240, 765, 832, 700, 520, 275, 731, 480, 480, 418, 
370, 480, 288, 350, 240, 315, 250, 688, 280, 266, 583, 798, 1104, 
1495, 1824, 570, 1045, 792, 902, 900, 588, 273, 201, 272, 520, 
544, 540, 630, 224, 350, 949, 1235, 2070, 1400, 1460, 1470, 1625, 
1809, 1650, 1625, 2650, 798, 1650, 240, 810, 1120, 30, 30, 30, 
330, 280, 300, 300, 120, 135, 495, 210, 180, 315, 125, 245, 245, 
300, 480, 18, 40, 16, 63, 88, 380, 12, 56, 35, 2, 45, 143, 88, 
56, 156, 36, 16, 20, 3, 2, 60, 56, 35, 10, 2, 10, 6, 12, 12, 
12, 48, 24, 4, 5, 16, 1, 36, 33, 54, 140, 130, 170, 90, 156, 
24, 24, 60, 4, 1, 50, 126, 112, 121, 80, 78, 18, 40, 27, 45, 
40, 33, 20, 30, 30, 120, 90, 40, 25, 20, 30, 30, 11, 100, 10, 
30, 30, 40, 25, 30, 20, 20, 20, 150, 100, 75, 90, 60, 30, 60, 
75, 150, 20, 60, 60, 150, 90, 40, 15, 472, 468, 200, 224, 270, 
132, 260, 258, 539, 522, 534, 492, 234, 231, 60, 258, 378, 312, 
156, 340, 192, 615, 645, 490, 455, 306, 210, 260, 555, 630, 688, 
850, 748, 1540, 1360, 1080, 1216, 70, 16, 18, 75, 63, 63, 24, 
42, 16, 9, 12, 80, 24, 8, 18, 6, 20, 15, 63, 156, 60, 30, 20, 
8, 8, 3, 14, 8, 4, 1, 52, 20, 10, 9, 1, 4, 6, 4, 35, 10, 4, 10, 
20, 2, 5, 10, 4, 4, 18, 18, 15, 12, 60, 4, 10, 1, 24, 10, 96, 
91, 96, 81, 99, 390, 132, 180, 187, 4, 15, 56, 30, 168, 35, 63, 
18, 60, 88, 209, 176, 99, 288, 192, 72, 81, 91, 20, 60, 135, 
96, 20, 252, 48, 72, 90, 81, 27, 2, 25, 4, 24, 72, 121, 77, 176, 
104, 273, 35, 24, 110, 24, 63, 96, 117, 156, 216, 210, 325, 32, 
25, 36, 84, 66, 84, 98, 90, 270, 20, 24, 45, 40, 33, 48, 56, 
60, 150, 108, 100, 80, 135, 64, 192, 117, 90, 108, 44, 24, 12, 
40, 132, 135, 108, 120, 208, 286, 299, 264, 12, 140, 35, 36, 
77, 12, 6, 3, 2, 1, 48, 130, 77, 120, 144, 132, 208, 165, 182, 
190, 35, 1, 12, 42, 96, 60, 6, 9, 12, 12, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 1, 6, 
8, 1, 9, 60, 60, 6, 30, 40, 28, 15, 64, 6, 4, 32, 4, 56, 20, 
48), State = c("DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", 
"DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", 
"DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", 
"DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", 
"DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", 
"DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", 
"DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", 
"DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", 
"DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", 
"DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", 
"DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", 
"DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", 
"DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", 
"DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", 
"DE", "DE", "DE", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", 
"IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", 
"IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", 
"IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", 
"IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", 
"IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", 
"IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", 
"IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", 
"IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", 
"IL", "IL", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", 
"MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", 
"MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", 
"MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", 
"MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", 
"MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", 
"MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", 
"MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", 
"MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", 
"MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", 
"MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", 
"MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", 
"MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", 
"MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", 
"MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", 
"MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", 
"MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", 
"MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", 
"MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", 
"MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", 
"MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", 
"MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", 
"MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO"), Year = c("2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014"), bar_colors = c("gold3", "gold3", "gold3", 
"gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", 
"gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", 
"gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", 
"gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", 
"gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", 
"gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", 
"gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", 
"gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", 
"gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", 
"gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", 
"gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", 
"gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", 
"gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", 
"gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", 
"gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", 
"gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", 
"gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", 
"gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", 
"gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", 
"gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", 
"gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", 
"gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "gold3", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", 
"darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", 
"darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", 
"darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", 
"darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", 
"darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", 
"darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", 
"darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", 
"darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", 
"darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", 
"darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", 
"darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", 
"darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", 
"darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", 
"darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", 
"darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", 
"darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", 
"darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", 
"darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", 
"darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", 
"darkgreen", "darkgrey", "darkgrey", "darkgrey", "darkgrey", 
"darkgrey", "darkgrey", "darkgrey", "darkgrey", "darkgrey", "darkgrey", 
"darkgrey", "darkgrey", "darkgrey", "darkgrey", "darkgrey", "darkgrey", 
"darkgrey", "darkgrey", "darkgrey", "darkgrey", "darkgrey", "darkgrey", 
"darkgrey", "darkgrey", "darkgrey", "darkgrey", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white")), .Names = c("UnitCode", "Minutes", 
"State", "Year", "bar_colors"), row.names = c(55L, 56L, 57L, 
58L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 274L, 275L, 
276L, 277L, 278L, 279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 285L, 286L, 
287L, 288L, 289L, 290L, 291L, 292L, 293L, 397L, 398L, 399L, 400L, 
401L, 402L, 403L, 404L, 405L, 406L, 407L, 408L, 409L, 410L, 411L, 
412L, 413L, 414L, 415L, 416L, 519L, 520L, 521L, 522L, 523L, 524L, 
525L, 526L, 527L, 528L, 529L, 530L, 531L, 532L, 533L, 534L, 535L, 
536L, 537L, 538L, 642L, 643L, 644L, 645L, 646L, 647L, 648L, 649L, 
650L, 651L, 652L, 653L, 654L, 655L, 656L, 657L, 658L, 659L, 660L, 
661L, 766L, 767L, 768L, 769L, 770L, 771L, 772L, 773L, 774L, 775L, 
776L, 777L, 778L, 779L, 780L, 781L, 782L, 783L, 784L, 785L, 889L, 
890L, 891L, 892L, 893L, 894L, 895L, 896L, 897L, 898L, 899L, 900L, 
901L, 902L, 903L, 904L, 905L, 906L, 907L, 908L, 928L, 929L, 930L, 
931L, 948L, 949L, 950L, 970L, 971L, 972L, 973L, 992L, 993L, 994L, 
1014L, 1015L, 1016L, 1017L, 1037L, 1038L, 1039L, 1040L, 2166L, 
2167L, 2168L, 2169L, 2170L, 2171L, 2172L, 2173L, 2174L, 2175L, 
2176L, 2254L, 2255L, 2256L, 2257L, 2258L, 2259L, 2260L, 2261L, 
2312L, 2313L, 2314L, 2315L, 2316L, 2317L, 2318L, 2319L, 2394L, 
2395L, 2396L, 2397L, 2398L, 2399L, 2400L, 2401L, 2402L, 2450L, 
2451L, 2452L, 2453L, 2454L, 2455L, 2456L, 2457L, 2458L, 2459L, 
2460L, 2464L, 2465L, 2523L, 2524L, 2525L, 2526L, 2527L, 2528L, 
2529L, 2530L, 2531L, 2532L, 2533L, 2683L, 2684L, 2685L, 2686L, 
2714L, 2715L, 2716L, 2717L, 2718L, 2719L, 2744L, 2753L, 2754L, 
2769L, 2770L, 2771L, 2772L, 2773L, 2774L, 2775L, 2776L, 2808L, 
2809L, 2810L, 2811L, 2812L, 2813L, 2837L, 2838L, 2839L, 2840L, 
2841L, 2850L, 2851L, 2852L, 2853L, 2854L, 2855L, 3002L, 3003L, 
3004L, 3005L, 3006L, 3007L, 3008L, 3009L, 3010L, 3011L, 3012L, 
3013L, 3014L, 3114L, 3115L, 3116L, 3117L, 3118L, 3119L, 3120L, 
3121L, 3122L, 3123L, 3124L, 3125L, 3126L, 5944L, 5945L, 5946L, 
5947L, 5948L, 5949L, 5950L, 5951L, 5952L, 5953L, 5954L, 6020L, 
6021L, 6022L, 6023L, 6024L, 6025L, 6026L, 6027L, 6075L, 6076L, 
6077L, 6078L, 6079L, 6080L, 6129L, 6130L, 6131L, 6132L, 6133L, 
6134L, 6135L, 6136L, 6137L, 6186L, 6187L, 6188L, 6189L, 6190L, 
6191L, 6192L, 6231L, 6232L, 6233L, 6234L, 6235L, 6252L, 6253L, 
6254L, 6255L, 6256L, 6257L, 6258L, 6259L, 6289L, 6290L, 6291L, 
6292L, 6293L, 6348L, 6349L, 6350L, 6351L, 6352L, 6353L, 6354L, 
6355L, 6421L, 6422L, 6423L, 6424L, 6425L, 6426L, 6427L, 6428L, 
6429L, 6430L, 6431L, 6501L, 6502L, 6503L, 6504L, 6505L, 6506L, 
6507L, 6508L, 6509L, 6510L, 6591L, 6592L, 6593L, 6594L, 6595L, 
6596L, 6597L, 6598L, 6599L, 6677L, 6678L, 6679L, 6680L, 6681L, 
6682L, 6683L, 6684L, 6685L, 6686L, 6741L, 6742L, 6743L, 6744L, 
6745L, 6746L, 6747L, 6748L, 6749L, 6750L, 6815L, 6816L, 6817L, 
6818L, 6819L, 6820L, 6821L, 6822L, 6823L, 6824L, 6825L, 6890L, 
6891L, 6892L, 6893L, 6894L, 6895L, 6896L, 6897L, 6898L, 6953L, 
6954L, 6955L, 6956L, 6957L, 6958L, 6959L, 6960L, 6961L, 7047L, 
7048L, 7049L, 7050L, 7051L, 7052L, 7053L, 7054L, 7055L, 7056L, 
7121L, 7122L, 7123L, 7124L, 7125L, 7126L, 7127L, 7128L, 7129L, 
7130L, 7131L, 7194L, 7195L, 7196L, 7197L, 7198L, 7199L, 7200L, 
7201L, 7202L, 7274L, 7275L, 7276L, 7277L, 7278L, 7279L, 7280L, 
7281L, 7282L, 7283L, 7284L, 7328L, 7329L, 7330L, 7331L, 7332L, 
7333L, 7334L, 7335L, 7336L, 7337L, 7357L, 7358L, 7359L, 7360L, 
7378L, 7379L, 7380L, 7381L, 7382L, 7404L, 7478L, 7479L, 7480L, 
7481L, 7482L, 7483L, 7484L, 7485L, 7486L, 7557L, 7558L, 7559L, 
7560L, 7561L, 7562L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the plot:

[image]

Here is the plot code:

```
  unit_effort_time = 
    ggplot(data=target_data,aes(x=UnitCode,y=Minutes,fill=bar_colors)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
    scale_fill_manual(name="State", 
                      values=unique(target_data$bar_colors),
                      labels=unique(target_data$State)) +
    theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
          axis.text.y=element_text(size=14, colour="black"),
          axis.title=element_text(size=20, face="bold"),
          legend.title=element_text(size=20, face="bold"),
          legend.text=element_text(size=14, face="bold"),
          panel.grid.major.x=element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank()) +
    ylab(as.character(paste0("Minutes ", "(2014)"))) +
    xlab("Survey Unit")
  unit_effort_time
```

Comment: If you remove the `labels` argument from `scale_fill_manual` I think you'll see what's happening.  It seems easiest to use `State` as the `fill` variable instead, but you could also try out`scale_fill_identity`.

Comment: That was it exactly! I was matching colors to colors. Changing `fill=bar_colors` to `fill=State` did the trick. Thanks! If you want to make it an answer I can select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem boils down to mapping `bar_colors` to `fill`.  By default, ggplot2 will assign levels of the fill alphabetically instead of the order they appear in the dataset.  When you were assigning the color values in `scale_fill_manual`, you were essentially assigning the colors in a different order than `fill` did, and things were mismatched.

If you wanted to go this route (using the colors as your `fill` variable), you'd want to explicitly make a factor variable and assign the `levels` in the order they appear in the dataset.  I made a separate variable, although you could have replaced the original character variable with the factor and used `levels` instead of `unique` in `scale_fill_manual`.

```
target_data$bar_colors2 = factor(target_data$bar_colors, levels = unique(target_data$bar_colors))

ggplot(data=target_data, aes(x=UnitCode, y=Minutes, fill=bar_colors2)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
    scale_fill_manual(name="State", 
                   values=unique(target_data$bar_colors),
                   labels = unique(target_data$State))
```

In your case, you can simplify all this by just using `State` directly as the `fill` variable.  Then assign the colors via `scale_fill_manual` and the unique values of `bar_colors` as before.  This is extra nice because the `labels` and `name` are then already set as you want them to be.

```
ggplot(data=target_data, aes(x=UnitCode, y=Minutes, fill=State)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
    scale_fill_manual(values=unique(target_data$bar_colors))
```